# Nexus 4 Notification bar unresponsive

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, notification-bar

My notification bar has suddenly become unresponsive. I have been unable to swipe down the bar no matter the orientation of my phone (regular and in landscape). I've played around with chrome to test the touch screen responsiveness and everything works fine. Is there a way I may have accidentally turned my notification bar off? Has anyone had this issue and know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Does that unresponsiveness persist after a reboot? Maybe some service went havoc.

Comment: @Izzy Even if it does not persist after reboot, that is a relevant bug. I have experienced it with my  3 days old Nexus 4. Maybe it's worth to file a bug report

Comment: @mdelolmo Agreed, if you can reproduce it. But here's the wrong place for "bug reports", as we cannot fix them. All we can do is help to figure out, and find possible work-arounds :)

Comment: Many owners of Nexus 4 experience this problem. See: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/mobile/3g6ZnYxKl_w/yhGAvDt1uGcJ

Comment: I experience it from time to time; quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a hard reboot (Power off the phone and power it back on). I had this problem just two minutes ago and that seemed to resolve it. Cheers!

Comment: This solves the problem for some users but not all. My friend who also has a Nexus 4 is able to solve it with a reboot, but it doesn't help on my phone